# heroku-toolbelt.pkg Installed on unknown location on Mac

Tags: macos, heroku-toolbelt

I have installed Heroku-toolbelt.pkg, but unable to find it on my Mac.

I want to migrate existing facebook on Hiroku after login, example code:-

```
$ heroku login
```

Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: adam@example.com
Password:

But I'm not able to find Hiroku.